# Duplicate OneToOne relation by Doctrine and SymfonySeoBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata, symfony-cmf

I add SEO data to my entity following this article http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/seo/seo_aware.html.

```php
    class Provider implements SeoAwareInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var SeoMetadataInterface
         *
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\SeoBundle\Model\SeoMetadata", cascade={"persist","remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="seo_metadata_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $seoMetadata;
    }
```

I use SonataAdmin to edit `Provider` entity and I use special form type for `seoMetadata` property - `SeoMetadataType` (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/seo/seo_aware.html#form-type)

```php
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
{
    $form
        // some entity related fields
        ->with('form.provider.seo_group_title', [
            'class' => 'col-md-4',
        ])
            ->add('seoMetadata', SeoMetadataType::class, [], [
                'generic_metadata' => false,
            ])
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

The problem is next - everytime I edit `Provider` entity I get new record of `SeoMetadata`.

I've debug updating process and before `persist` and `flush` operation I have proxy of `SeoMetadata` in `$seoMetadata` property with existed `id`, but after `persist` and `flush` operations I see proxy with new `id` and new record in table.

Anybody have idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We do have some ORM examples, but do not fully support it atm. But can you reproduce your issue of persistence only by adding some code here: https://github.com/symfony-cmf/seo-bundle/blob/master/tests/Functional/Doctrine/Orm/SeoMetadataTest.php Simply do a PR and i will try to fix it. But it can also be, that the issue is in sonata or in the forms.